# Degree of a determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $p$ be a prime number and $n\in\mathbb N$. Consider the determinant

$$M_n = \begin{vmatrix}\frac1{x^{p^{n+1}}-x}&\frac1{x^{p^{n+1}}-x^p}\\ \frac1{x^{p^{n+2}}-x}&\frac1{x^{p^{n+2}}-x^p}\end{vmatrix} \in \mathbb F_p(x)$$

Numerical computations suggest that

$$\deg(M_n)=p-(p+2)p^{n+1}$$

Is it true? Is yes, does anyone have an idea to prove it?

Comment: What do you mean by degree?

Comment: I don't see how the determinant happens to be an element of $\mathbb F_p[x]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that by degree you mean degree of the numerator minus the degree of the denominator, this is a trivial calculation.  The determinant is $$\frac{1}{(x^{p^{n+1}}-x)(x^{p^{n+2}}-x^p)}-\frac{1}{(x^{p^{n+2}}-x)(x^{p^{n+1}}-x^p)}.$$  Multiplying the denominators of these fractions to combine them gives a denominator of degree $2(p^{n+1}+p^{n+2})$.  In the combined numerator, the $x^{p^{n+1}+p^{n+2}}$ terms will cancel, leaving the highest degree term in the numerator as $x^{p^{n+2}+p}$.  So the degree of the numerator minus the degree of the denominator is $$(p^{n+2}+p)-2(p^{n+1}+p^{n+2})=p-(p+2)p^{n+1}.$$